# Using requests module to log out the user

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post

I need help in constructing post request for the logout from web-site. The source code for the logout button(actually it's not a button) is the following:

```
<a tabindex="9" title="Log Out" href="/logout.jsp?submit_ButtonOK=true" onclick="removeLoginCookie();">Log Out</a>
```

My code doesn't work. The user is still logged in after script performes.

```
logout = requests.post(url+'/logout.jsp?submit_ButtonOK=true')
print logout.url
```

I think the problem is in cookies that are kept after login.

that's my whole code(of course it's not finished):

```
import requests, time
payload = {
'UserName_Text'     : 'user',
'UserPW_Password'   : 'pass',
'submit_ButtonOK'   : 'return buttonClick;'
    }
url = 'url'
p = requests.post(url+'/login.jsp', data = payload) #login
print p.url

timer = requests.get(url+'/login.jsp').elapsed.total_seconds()
print timer

logout = requests.get(url+'/logout.jsp', params={'submit_ButtonOK' :'true'})
print logout.url
```

Comment: That looks dodgy for 2 reasons. 1 - You shouldn't make any changes (such as log out) on a GET request. 2 - It looks like the javascript in the page will remove the cookie even if the request to the server fails (e.g. network problems).

Comment: The link will use a GET request but your code is using POST. Perhaps try with a GET (and have a word with the JSP implementor that it should probably be POST after all).

Comment: So, with your script (on your server) you're trying to log the user out from some other server? That's not possible.

Comment: @georg Well, it *is* possible if he knows the session ID for that user and provides it in the logout request :)

Comment: @IgorHatarist: yes, it's also "possible" to get an axe and physically destroy the other server, thus effectively logging out everybody ;) but it looks to me that the OP simply misunderstands the basics of http, let's not confuse them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like a `POST` request - when you click on hyperlinks, the browser sends a `GET` request.
(Well, the `removeLoginCookie` function could override it and send a `POST` request instead.)

Also, determine what the cookie name is and then call something like that (depending on the how `removeLoginCookie` works and what name does it use to store the session key):

```
r = requests.get(url + 'logout.jsp', params={'submit_ButtonOK': 'true'}, cookies={'logged_in': 'false', 'session': ''})
```

Comment: Check my whole code please, any advise? How can I find cookies?

Comment: Can you track exactly what kind of request sends your browser? Afterwards, it is much easier to determine what you should do.

You can get cookies from your response object via field ``cookies``.

Comment: I've got JSESSIONID cookie that contains this "709BA8EF59AB75A105C8C841B4F54661"

Comment: Thank you all. Managed to resolve my problem sending session cookies.